# Add sorting to a namedtuple

Tags: python, sorting

I currently override the sorting methods provided by `namedtuple` by doing something like this:

```
class Subtitle(namedtuple('Subtitle', ['index', 'start', 'end', 'content'])):
    def __eq__(self, other): return self.start == other.start
    def __ne__(self, other): return self.start != other.start
    def __lt__(self, other): return self.start <  other.start
    def __le__(self, other): return self.start <= other.start
    def __gt__(self, other): return self.start >  other.start
    def __ge__(self, other): return self.start >= other.start
```

Typically I would use `functools.total_ordering` as a decorator to fill in the other sort methods from one, but in this case, `collections.namedtuple` already defines sort methods, so decorating with it has no effect.

As it is, fleshing out all of these comparisons when they can be deduced from each other seems a waste of code -- something that is much better handled by `functools.total_ordering` if only I could use it. I suppose I could delete the other sort methods from the object, but that seems quite messy. I'm not interested in reimplementing something like `functools.total_ordering` from scratch in my code.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @ferada: Did you read my question fully? I've already gone over why `functools.total_ordering` is not adequate by itself .

Comment: Ah, yes, my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use multiple inheritance:

```
@functools.total_ordering
class SubtitleOrdering(object):
    def __eq__(self, other): return self.start == other.start
    def __lt__(self, other): return self.start <  other.start

class Subtitle(SubtitleOrdering, namedtuple('Subtitle', ['index', 'start', 'end', 'content'])):
    pass
```

`total_ordering` works normally on `SubtitleOrdering`, and making it the first base class overrides the comparison methods of the `namedtuple`.

Comment: Hm. This seems reasonable, but perhaps overcomplicated if this is only being done once. I will consider this method -- thanks!